# ffmpeg - Dynamic letters and random position watermark to video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am making an online course, and to avoid piracy distribution I thought to put watermarks on the videos (including personal user information) so it cannot upload to sharing websites. Now the hard part: I would move the watermark during the video, in 3/4 random positions, every 30 seconds.
It is possibile with ffmpeg?

Comment: Duplicate of [Making jumping text watermark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291331/making-jumping-text-watermark).

Comment: **The "ffmpeg" tag is only allowed for programmatic use of the ffmpeg API** - Questions about the command-line use should be asked on Super-user or Video-production.

Comment: yeah but you can use the command line on a server for programmatic use, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: this is an adaptation of the answer in LN's link, which will randomize the position every 30 seconds with no repeats:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-vf \
"drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=80:fontcolor=yellow@0.5:text='studentname': \
 x=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(W-tw))\,x): \
 y=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(H-th))\,y)" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

---

**Older answer**

You can use a command like the one below:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-vf \
"drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=80:fontcolor=yellow@0.5: \
 text='studentname':x=200:y=350:enable='between(mod(t\,30*3),0,30)', \
 drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=80:fontcolor=yellow@0.5: \
 text='studentname':x=1000:y=600:enable='between(mod(t\,30*3),31,60)', \
 drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=80:fontcolor=yellow@0.5: \
 text='studentname':x=450:y=50:enable='between(mod(t\,30*3),61,90)'" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Here, three positions are rotated with a change occurring every 30 seconds. Each `x:y` parameter is manually set. If you're calling the command from a shell script, you can use a random number generator and feed that into the command. There is a random function included in the drawtext filter, but it is evaluated *each frame*, so that will result in a pseudo ping pong game with the text.

Comment: It is an interesting example, and I've seen enough similar questions like this that I think it could be useful to add it to the drawtext examples in `doc/filters.texi` if you feel like submitting a patch.

Comment: Sounds good. Can you point to a guide on how to format and submit a doc patch? Thanks.

Comment: [Clone ffmpeg repo using git](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html). [Add name and email to git global config](https://wiki.videolan.org/git#Configure_your_global_git_config) and navigate to `ffmpeg` directory. Always rebase first: `git pull --rebase`. Make local branch: `git checkout -b drawrandom`. Make edits. Locally commit changes: `git commit -as` (see [example commit titles and messages](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=history;f=doc/filters.texi)). Review log `git log -p -2`, make patch: `git format-patch -o patches origin`. Email file in `patches` to ffmpeg-devel at ffmpeg.

Comment: Also see [Using Git to develop FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/git-howto.html). Most devs use `git send-email` but that involves some added complexity to setup.

Comment: Can someone please explain logic and details of this expression from the example above: x=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(W-tw))\,x) ? I know that it's responsible for random repositioning by X axis, every 30 seconds. But how it all works - those: if, eq, mod, t, rand, \ ?

Comment: The expression for x and y are of the form : `if(condition,then,else)`. If condition is true, the `then` clause is executed; if false, the `else` clause is executed. `eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)` is true only for `t=0,30,60,90...`. At those times, x and y are set to a random position which keeps the full text on screen. At all other times, the text remains still till the next change happens.