# ffmpeg - adding Dynamic logo & random position watermark to video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-watermarking

I am making a tutorial for sending through mail to my uses, and to avoid piracy distribution I thought to put watermarks (`logo.png`) at random places at interval on the videos.

I tried using the command from [ffmpeg - Dynamic letters and random position watermark to video?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36363661/):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
-vf \
"drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=80:fontcolor=yellow@0.5:text='studentname': \
 x=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(W-tw))\,x): \
 y=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(H-th))\,y)" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

But it gave me error:

```
[NULL @ 0x55c812525600] Unable to find a suitable output format for '\'
\: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backslashes (`\`) at the end of each line and make the command one line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=80:fontcolor=yellow@0.5:text='studentname':x=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(W-tw))\,x):y=if(eq(mod(t\,30)\,0)\,rand(0\,(H-th))\,y)" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy output.mp4
```